# I'm having a question OR I'm having one question - Which sounds better?

Tags: articles, determiners

Can anyone please tell me, what would be a nicer way to ask a single question to a project manager or a team leader?

**I'm having *a* question OR I'm having *one* question.**

Which one is preferable?

Comment: You cannot say either of those. Unless you're having fries with your burger, you cannot say *am having*. Questions aren't going to be served to you on a platter.

Comment: "I have a question," would suffice. Or just ask the question without prefacing it.

Comment: Neither sounds very good.

Answer (score 3):

In British and American English, people say, "I have a question."

"I am having a question" is considered incorrect in the UK or the USA. However, the overuse of the progressive appears to characteristic of Indian English, so it is possible that "I am having a question" might be acceptable in India. See for example the following student paper: *["Are you wanting a cup of coffee?" Overuse of the progressive aspect in Indian English](https://kops.uni-konstanz.de/bitstream/handle/123456789/3793/Schubert_exam.pdf;sequence=1)* (2002).

Comment: +1 thanks for the link to the paper, coincidentally I was mulling this very [question of overuse of the progressive just minutes ago](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338445/why-raining-why-not-rain-is-coming#comment778543_338445).