# Why "It is raining?" instead of "Rain is coming"?

Tags: differences, pronouns, expression-choice

People will normally say, "It's raining". Why can't it be, "Rain is coming?"

Comment: No no it's not rain you smell: *winter is coming*.

Comment: Yes, you may say that: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rain+is+coming&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crain%20is%20coming%3B%2Cc0, though "its raining" is more idiomatic.

Comment: "Rain is coming" means it's not yet arrived; "It's raining" means it has.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I think OP means: "rain is coming down".

Comment: @Josh61 I wonder why IndE speakers so strongly prefer, really powerful prefer, the present progressive. Maybe that tense enjoys a closer analogy to Hindi or Gurjati? Or maybe it sounds "manifestly more present" than the simple present? I have picked up they're big fans of emphasis.

Comment: @DanBron - you could make it a question. Cultural issues reflected by the language.

Comment: @Josh61 Recently, few of my questions have received much attention or definitive answers. It's a bit discouraging.

Comment: @DanBron - yeah, but don't give up...you should probably use bounties also.

Comment: @Josh61 Check out [the link in this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/338446/55623), posted just minutes ago: what a coincidence!

Comment: @Dan Bron - interesting, thanks. But "I am living it" is not Indian :)

Comment: @Josh61 Where did you get "I am living it?". FWIW, that paper says IndE prefers the progressive for stative verbs (of perception and cognition).

Comment: @Dan Bron - sorry, a typo. I meant  ***"I am loving it"*** :)

Comment: @Josh61 Haha, that's *consciously* a slang-y slogan used by a cynical multinational conglomerate to "connect" to their customers in impoverished urban areas. though you're right that to an extent, AAVE shares something of this affinity for the progressive. Another corporate ad has a shoe salesman asking a prospective customer *You seeing something you feelin'?* (meaning: *You see a pair of shoes you like/which speak to you?*).

Comment: You can pretty much say anything you want, short of libel or slander.  But saying "rain is coming" (rather than "rain is coming down") would generally be taken to mean "rain is expected".

Answer (score 3):

That's just how some idomatic expressions work. In English, *it* is sometimes used as a subject, as in *it's raining*, *it's sunny*, *it's warm*.

Of course it would be possible to say *rain is falling*, *the sun is shining*, *the weather is warm*, and sometimes people *do* say that. Most commonly, though, people tend to use the shorter, familiar idioms.

About *rain is coming*: this is not an uncommon expression, but it means that it will start to rain *in the near future*, so it doesn't mean the same as *it's raining*.

An example of [rain is falling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svqjijZHQrI) is the ELO song. Obviously, in song lyrics, people sometimes choose their words based on rhyme or rythm rather than idiom (although [Supertramp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZUE4_PtOk0) sang *it's raining again*!)